# Spring profile based on conditions

Tags: java, spring, configuration

Is it possible to register bean based on some expression of active profiles
ex.

```
  @Profile(!prod)

  @Profile(name!="test")
```

I have a situation at which i need to configure beans based on many different conditions, is that possible in Spring?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `@Profile("!test")` to register the bean if the `test` profile is not active.

EDIT: Also, in Spring 4, you can use the [Condition](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Condition.html) interface to create complex regex-based conditions. See [this tutorial](https://raymondhlee.wordpress.com/2015/05/31/using-spring-4-condition-to-control-bean-registration/).